Ошибка NoClassDefFoundError в Android studio
Есть код для тестирования:

Clean и rebuild уже пробовал.
Не знаю поможет ли код самого файла QuizViewModel, но на всякий случай прикрепляю:

В целом приложение работает без ошибок. Почему именно при тестировании возникает NoClassDefFoundError?

Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! рекомендую ознакомиться со справкой => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask // https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12119/264178

Приведите полный стектрейс ошибки. В нем будет указано где конкретно ClassNotFoundException в QuizViewModel.
